# How can I reauthorize DVC with Google Drive for remote storage?

Tags: dvcs, dvc

I am using DVC to keep track of my data and steps in my machine learning project. I am trying to setup a remote using google drive. This is not necessarily difficult and i used the [documentation](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/data-management/remote-storage/google-drive) from dvc.

I get an error when i try to use `dvc push`

```
ERROR: unexpected error - Failed to authenticate GDrive: Access token refresh failed: invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.
```

The first time i used the command i got redirected to the google drive login page and could give dvc permission to edit files. I think i forgot to give it the right permissions but if i now rerun the command i do not get send to the login page. Does anyone know how to get the login again to google drive and give the right permissions to dvc.

I already tried completly removing everything related to dvc from my project but this did not seem to help

Answer (score 3):

What are looking for is described on the [Google Drive for DVC](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/data-management/remote-storage/google-drive) page under the [`gdrive_user_credentials_file`](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/data-management/remote-storage/google-drive#configuration-parameters) option.

Namely, the default is `$CACHE_HOME/pydrive2fs/{gdrive_client_id}/default.json` (unless profile is specified), where the `CACHE_HOME` location per platform is:

| macOS | Linux (*typical) | Windows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `~/Library/Caches` | `~/.cache` | `%CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA%` |

You should be able to drop the file and run `dvc pull`, `dvc push` (or any other DVC command that would actually involve DVC accessing the remote storage) to generate the file again.

If it happens often, you can use the very same option `drive_user_credentials_file` to customize the location for this file.

```bash
$ dvc remote modify myremote \
      gdrive_user_credentials_file path/to/mycredentials.json
```

[Here](https://github.com/iterative/PyDrive2/issues/184) is the related discussion on why the refresh token expires. There are options (service account with delegation, or publishing an app to make the refresh token more permanent, use the built-in DVC app for now). They all have certain benefits and downsides. Please chime in the ticket or here to discuss them.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is not too late.
I ran into the same issue. Here is how to fix it.

check if there is a file located at this location:

$CACHE_HOME/pydrive2fs/{gdrive_client_id}/default.json

This file holds your credentials. If there is such file it might be corrupted,removing it could solve the issue.

$CACHE_HOME is:

~/Library/Caches for MacOS,

~/.cache for Linux,

and %CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA% for Windows.